# AWS lambda to renew sts role at each invocation is time consuming

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I would like to know about a  more efficient way than renewing sts role for a cross account role when it run on lambda. By definition those roles last for 1h per default, but so far i'm doing it this way:

```
def aws_session(role_arn, session_name):
    _ = boto3.client('sts')
    resp = _.assume_role(RoleArn=role_arn, RoleSessionName=session_name)
    session = boto3.Session(
        aws_access_key_id=response['Credentials']['AccessKeyId'],
        aws_secret_access_key=response['Credentials']['SecretAccessKey'],
        aws_session_token=response['Credentials']['SessionToken'],
        region_name='us-east-1')
    return session


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    session = aws_session(role_arn=ARN, session_name='CrossAccountLambdaRole')
    s3_sts = session.resource('s3')
```

But it terribly inefficient because instead of ~300ms, renewing credentials take more than ~1500 ms each time and as we all know, we are charged on the duration execution. Anyone could help me on how to refresh this only when the token expire ? Coz between execution, we are not sure to endup using the same "container", so how to make global variable?
Thx a lot

Comment: What is the ARN? Is it for another account?

Comment: yes, sts here is to call a iam role cross account

Comment: My 2 cents: this is still the fastest method. Let's say you store the credentials in a DynamoDB. When storing it, you need to store the token and expiration time in the table. When retrieving the credentials from DDB, you need to validate the current time and compare it with the expiration time and if expired, you need to regenerate the credentials and store it back in DDB. It would take more time to do this than `assume_role`.

Comment: thx :) yeah no, dynamodb isn't an option just to handle this temp credential.. I was hoping smth more straighforward, but if not, i will stick to those 1.5s lag :/

Comment: It could be DDB / parameter store / SQS

Comment: *"so how to make global variable"*  Just make global variables.  If, when invoked, you find that the variables were alreasy initialized and the stored credentials are still valid (not expired), then use them.  If not, obtain new ones.  The response object also contains `Expiration` -- the time the temporary credentials expire, which you can test.  A container doesn't run more than one invocation of the function at a time.  Containers are frequently reused.

Comment: What do you mean credentials are renewed on each invocation? You've set the expiration to 1 hour. Are you saying every time your lambda function is called the credentials are being renewed and the 1 hour expiration is ignored?

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil yeap , each call renew sts credentials, thus ignoring possible expiration time, not premium solution

Comment: @jthemovie Something else is going on. The whole purpose of the expiration field is for it to to extend the lifetime of the credentials. How can you tell they are being renewed on every request before 1 hour is reached?

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil That is the whole point of my question here ;) Renewing non expired credentials each call is not ideal..., on any other vm, container its easy to deal with it, but on lambda i do not see any other solution (apart external DBs), i have business support, i should may as well ask them ;)

Comment: @jthemovie What I mean is I don't think Lambda is the cause, thats its probably your integration points. I've used temporary credentials via STS and Lambda and only had to refresh once per hour. Can you add more info about your architecture. And my other question is how do you know the credentials are being refreshed each time? Is this from CloudTrail logs?

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil So please share some snippet, python, node, java, i take it all ;) . I know it coz if i print the accessKey , its a different one every time lambda is ran, pretty much couple of times per seconds

Answer (score 1):

**Remove AssumeRole**

I think your problem stems from the fact that your code is picking the role it needs on each run. Your assume role code should indeed be generating a new token on each call. I'm not familiar with the Python Boto library but in Node I only call AssumeRole when I'm testing locally and want to pull down new credentials, I save those credentials and never call assume role again until I want new creds. Every time I call assume role, I get new credentials as expected. You don't need STS directly to run your lambda functions.

**An Alternate Approach:**

For the production application my Lambda code does not pick its role. The automation scripts that build the Lambda function assign it a role and the lambda function will use that role for ever, with AWS managing the refresh of credentials on the back-end as they expire. You can do this by building your Lambda function in CloudFormation specifying what role you want it to use.

**Lambda via CloudFormation**
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html

If you then want to view what credentials your function is operating with you can print out environment variables. Lambda will pass in temporary credentials to your function and the credentials will be associated with the role you've defined.

**Simpler Approach**

If you don't want to deal with CloudFormation deploy your function manually into the AWS console and in the console specify the role it should run with. But the bottom line is you don't need to use STS inside your lambda code. Assign the role externally.

Answer (score 1):

Since your going across accounts, you obviously can't follow the advice many people say of attaching directly to the lambda.

Your best option is parameter store which is covered in detail here:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/sharing-secrets-with-aws-lambda-using-aws-systems-manager-parameter-store/

Simply have lambda request the credentials from there instead.

That said, it's probably not going to save much time compared to STS requests... But I've not timed either process.

A perhaps less-good way, that's fairly simple, is to store the credentials in /TMP and build a process around enduring the credentials remain valid -- perhaps assume role with 65 minute duration, and save to a time stamped file with the minutes/seconds dropped. If the file exists, read it in by file I/O.

Keep in mind your saving credentials in a way that can be compromised if your code allows access to read the file in some way... Though as a lambda and with shared responsibility security, it's reasonably secure compared to doing this strategy on a persistent server.

Always use least privilege roles. Only allow your trusted account to assume this role... I think your can even lock trust policies down to a specific incoming lambda role as allowed to assume role in. This way leaked credentials by somehow reading/outputting the file require a malicious user to compromise some other aspect of your account (if locked down by account number only), or execute remote code execution inside your lambda itself (if locked to lambda).... Though, at that point, your credentials are already available to the malicious user to use anyways.